# Showing Entries based on an Entries Field but also showing a slug in the url

Tags: filter, relatedto

I have a Channel 'Articles' with an Entries field which is linked to entries in 'Staff Members' channel.  This is so that articles can be assigned to different members of staff.

I have the generic listing (all articles) page working fine I just need to show the same page but filtered by a selected staff memeber. E.g. When viewing an individual article by a member of staff I would like to link to a page which only lists the articles assigned to that particular staff member.  This far would be ok but if possible I would also like to get the staff member name into the url... http://mysite/staff/joe-bloggs/articles

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set up a custom route in `config/routes.php` so that that URI points to your existing listing template:

```php
return [
    'staff/<route_staffMember>/articles' => ['template' => '_listings/default'],
];
```

Then simply use the `relatedTo` parameter to alter which entries get listed. The template will have access to a variable called `route_staffMember` which you can use to fork logic between the filtered/non-filtered views. (I like to prefix these variables with `route_` because when I look at the code 6 months later I always scratch my head wondering where this magic variable is being set!)

For example:

```
_listings/default

{% set staffMemberId = route_staffMember is defined ? craft.entries.section('staff').slug(route_staffMember).ids() : null %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('articles').relatedTo(staffMemberId).all() %}

{# ...or, if you're using pagination: #}
{% paginate craft.entries.section('articles').relatedTo(staffMemberId).limit(12) as pageInfo, entries %}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is out of my brain range!  I have set it up as you suggest but I get 'template not found'.  I think I may be using the wrong method to link to the page?  On the individual article page I have a link that looks like this <a href="/staff/{{ staff.title|kebab }}/articles">See more articles by {{ staff.title }}</a>.   I'm setting the 'staff' variable with {% set staff = entry.linkArticleWithStaffMember.one() %}  where linkArticleWithStaffMember is an entries field.

Comment: It should work ok... double-check your syntax. What is your template called that you want to route to? I named mine `_listings/default` - be sure to change that to whatever template you're using.